# Is, "deliberately" dropping articles almost equal to the English grammar?

Tags: word-usage, definite-article, zero-article

Can we say we can call it the English grammar when the speaker drops the articles because of the difficulties of the pronunciation??????

For example, please listen to the [link's speech.](http://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2016/02/26/468297948/u-s-proposes-tough-new-sanctions-on-north-korea-with-chinas-support)

The U.S ambasssador Samantha says at from 2:35 ～

> "I think that China is genuinely worried about the threat, Kim Jung Un, and his nuclear programms poses to the penninsula and to **international peace security**....."

Now, I am assuming due to the difficulties of the pronunciation, the definite article "the" was intentionally (or unconsciously) dropped. I think this is very strange because she is using the definite article *"the"* before the word *pennnisula* but not before *"international peace security".* ' which is singular)

Can I consider this kind of "habits" or "tendencies", which I find many times when I listen to something, as the "correct" or "standard" English grammar?

I guess it is happening without being paid due attention by the native speakers (even by the U.S ambassador! ).

Comment: You misquote: she says "international peace and security". And she is speaking of a general state, not a specific instance of international peace and security.

Comment: Abstract nouns like "security" often do not get an article in English.

Comment: I am sorry to say, what is the "specific" instance of the international peace and secutiry? The overall article is dealing with all the things concerning with Norh Korea.

Comment: Okay, for example, then from 3:20 ～ she is saying "I think that was **the**  greater irritation of China". Is the word "irritation" not abstract?????

Comment: I don't really understand what this question is asking, but it seems to be based on a misunderstanding of how articles are used in English.

Comment: Listen carefully, she said “[...] that was a source of great irritation for China.”

Comment: “A” refers to “source”, not “irritation”. I don't know what you're trying to say; what she said was correct. Ask what's really troubling you ([X Y Problem.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)).

Comment: So the conclusion is, if the following noun is "abstract", we can not put the article either "a" or "the". Am I getting correctly? Thank you.

Comment: It is not about it being abstract or not.  Abstract nouns often take articles (_"A love like the love that they shared is a thing of beauty."_) It is about it being specific or general.  I tagged your question with _"zero-article"  Please read some of the other questions and answers that share that tag for more discussion of the concept.  Here's a solid one: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37277/zero-article-meaning-some-particular-thing

Comment: I said abstract nouns "often" do not get an article, not that they "cannot." They can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article wasn't dropped - it is correctly non-present. The general concept at play here is sometimes called "zero article" or "zero marking."  The sentence would sound very strange to me if it had an article. Similarly, "Can we say we can call it the English grammar...." should not have an article.

It is not about it being abstract or not. Abstract nouns often take articles ("A love like the love that they shared is a thing of beauty.") Conversely, concrete nouns sometimes take no article.  (For instance, your last sentence, *I guess it is happening without being paid due attention by the native speakers.*  Should be *I guess it is happening without being paid due attention by native speakers* )

Zero article is common for both plural and uncountable nouns.:

- *Do you like meat?*

  ***Meat***  is uncountable, not plural, and I am asking about the general class of things which could be considered to be meat.
- *I feel pain in my left leg.*

  ***Pain*** is uncountable.
- *I train chickens.*

  ***Chickens*** is plural.
- *Godzilla threatens world peace*

  ***World peace*** is uncountable.

Back to your original quote:

> "I think that China is genuinely worried about the threat, Kim Jung Un, and his nuclear programs poses to the penninsula and to international peace security.

You misheard it slightly, but in ways that change meaning.  The transcript below the sound file gets it right:

> I think China's genuinely worried about the threat that Kim Jong-un and his nuclear weapons program poses to the peninsula and to international peace and security.

*International peace and security* is being used to refer to two general ideas, not a specific episode of peace, or a detente between two countries, so it correctly does not have an article.  Contrast with:

> The peace and stability of Northeast Asia depends on the ability of South Korea, Japan and the United States to cooperate effectively to meet whatever challenges Pyongyang may pose.
>   (From [National Interest](http://www.nationalinterest.org/blog/the-buzz/time-bolder-us-japan-south-korea-trilateral-15695)

Here there is a specific peace in a specific reason that is being discussed, so the direct article is appropriate.

Another example:

> February 3, 1959 was an important day in history.

History is a general uncountable idea

**VS**

> February 3, 1959 was an important day in *the* history of rock and roll

Now we have a specific little subset of history.

Comment: Thank you for your answer anway. I think I am getting into a deeper and deeper place somehow..............sorry to say like this though.

Comment: So, she, Samantha, is talking about the "general" "international peace security" even though they ( Samantha and the narrator ) are dealing with a specific issue. Am I O.K?

Comment: Correct.  Also see my edits.

Comment: May be, the reason why I was puzzled by this kind of thing is, Samantha suddenly "jumped" onto the wider issue. She talked about Korean penninsuia ('s danger ) but, would someone think that North Korea could pose a world wide great danger like Russia......